# Как привязать переменную к чату?

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу бота на питоне для телеграма, использую библиотеку pytelegrambotapi. Использую глобальную переменную, но когда пользователь в другом чате записывает свое значение в нее, оно меняется и в моем чате.

Comment: попробуйте словарь {чат:значение}

Comment: На то она и глобальная, рекомендую Вам изучить область видимости объектов python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте глобальный словарь, в котором ключом будет id пользователя.